# Trying to Connect to azure cosmos client using python, Gives 104 connection aborted error

Tags: python, mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Okay so I have an azure cosmos subscription, where I have created a Mongo DB resource, Now when I am using python SDK to connect it, now it's given when **104, error**, `connection reset by peer`.

Now I am not sure what's the issue, 
I am using endpoint with SSL True and Primary Key.

```
code
endpoint = "http://XXX.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true"
key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

# <create_cosmos_client>
client = CosmosClient(endpoint, key)
```

Comment: post your code here

Comment: done added code

Comment: The Cosmos DB client is specific to the SQL API. For the MongoDB API, you need to use the native MongoDB SDK.

Answer (score 1):

When choosing the MongoDB API, you must use a native MongoDB SDK (in your case, `pymongo`); the wire protocol is MongoDB, and operations are performed via the same protocol as MongoDB.

Your code is attempting to use the Cosmos DB SDK, which is specific to, and will only work with, the Core (SQL) API.

If you look in the portal blade for your MongoDB-API instance, you'll see examples under Quick Start tab, which each use a MongoDB SDK in its examples (or the `mongo` shell). Same thing with the Connection Strings tab, showing native MongoDB connection strings (as well as the separate parts of the connection string).